# Need to close database connection for session

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I have the following code, basically lifted from http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1333/PHP-5-sessions-in-mysql-database-with-PDO-db-objects

The thing which strikes me as a bit strange is that there's nothing in there to close the database connection (i.e. setting $this->db = null). Should I be worried about that (or anything else here)? Specifically, should I put $this->db = null in the close() function or does close() here mean something else? :)

```
public $db;
public $maxlifetime = 1800; /* 30 mins */
public $expiry;

public function __destruct(){
session_write_close();
}

public function open( $path, $name ) {
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . MySQLConfigClass::MySql_SERVERNAME . ';dbname=' . MySQLConfigClass::MySql_DBNAME, MySQLConfigClass::MySql_LOGINNAME, MySQLConfigClass::MySql_PASS);
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return true;
}

public function close() {
return true;
}

public function read($se_id){
$qry = "select se_value from sessions where se_id = '$se_id' and se_expires > " . time();
$sth = $this->db->prepare($qry);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result['se_value'];
}

public function write($se_id, $se_val){
$this->expiry = time() + $this->maxlifetime;
try {
$qry= "insert into sessions (se_id, se_value, se_expires) values('$se_id', '$se_val', $this->expiry)";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($qry);
$sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
$qry= "update sessions set se_value='$se_val', se_expires=$this->expiry where se_id='$se_id'";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($qry);

$sth->execute();
}
}

public function destroy($se_id){
$qry = "delete from sessions where se_id ='$se_id'";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($qry);
$tot= $sth->execute();
return ($tot);
}

public function gc($maxlifetime){
$qry = "delete from sessions where se_expires < ".time();
$sth = $this->db->prepare($qry);
$tot= $sth->execute();
return ($tot);
}
}

$session = new Session;
session_set_save_handler(
array(&$session, "open"),
array(&$session, "close"),
array(&$session, "read"),
array(&$session, "write"),
array(&$session, "destroy"),
array(&$session, "gc")
);

session_start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PDO, the database connection is closed automatically as soon as the database object (created by `new PDO()`) is destroyed. See [Connections and connection management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) in the PHP PDO documentation.

If you set `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` when you create your PDO object, however, the connection will be cached and reused on subsequent page loads, provided they use the same credentials for the database.

Comment: Is there anywhere here where the object is actually destoyed?

Comment: The code you posted is just a wrapper class, so it will be destroyed when the object you instantiate from it goes out of scope.

Comment: Does this still hold true if setting PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ?

Comment: That wasn't in your original question, but I added it to my answer anyway. Enjoy :)

Comment: True true, so I'll accept your answer- though I'd appreciate your insight a little further. If using persistent connections, should I add $this->dbh = null to the close() method here? If not, where/how should I?

Comment: Maybe, or maybe not. It depends on your own code. You should perhaps study [how scope works in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

When you remove all references to the PDO object (such as by setting the variable that referenced it to `null`), the connection is closed.  The same thing happens when PHP exits.  There is nothing you have to do.

Also, you might have some bad SQL injection vulnerabilities there!  You are already using prepared queries... be sure to use parameters for any variable data.

Comment: Thanks- that's a good point about the params, will change it... I understand that setting the variable to null will close the connection, my concern is that it's not set to null anywhere here

Comment: @davidkomer, It doesn't have to be.  As soon as the script finishes executing, garbage collection occurs and the connection is disconnected.  Your script is fine.  Nothing to worry about.